# Chart.js bar chart minimum bar width

Tags: chart.js

How do I set a minimum bar width for a Chart.js bar chart? When I have many bars, they become very thin in order to fit the given space. Instead, I want the bars to have a minimum width, and if necessary, there should be a scrollbar so that everything fits. There is a `maxBarThickness` but not a `minBarThickness`: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#maxbarthickness.

Comment: Does my answer solve your question? or am I missing something? If so please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the **min** setting is achieved with `barThickness` check [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness) for details.

> *... If this value is a number, it is applied to the width of each bar, in pixels. When this is enforced, barPercentage and categoryPercentage are ignored. ...*